# "ImportError: No module named Tkinter" in sikuli

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, sikuli

The objective is to create a GUI for a Sikuli script.  The GUI is for prompting the user to select a folder.  I wanted to check whether Sikuli supports tk or not.  So I opened the Sikuli IDE and made a script named "gui.sikuli" with only one line in it:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

And when I run it, it gave an error saying "ImportError: No module named Tkinter".  Does Sikuli support tk? If not, then what can I use to create GUI for Sikuli code? If yes, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jython does not support Tkinter library. Quoting http://www.jython.org/faq3.html :

*Modules that we **don't support**, and perhaps won't, include ... **Tkinter** ...*

Fortunately Sikuli provides its own simple GUI: http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#interacting-with-the-user

For purpose of getting directory path you should use *input* function:

```
dirPath = input("Please enter your folder path:")
```

Comment: Suppose If I want to get three inputs from a user and if I use input() function for it, it will popup thrice one after one. Is there anyothere way to have all those three popups appearing once at time in a single GUI????

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to customize Sikuli input function. It creates modal window and program waits until it is closed. Otherwise you would need to run it in a separate thread which is too complicated for this task. You can also try to create  your own GUI in Jython Swing: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/GUIApplications.html .